# Exporting Eclipse Snippets

Tags: eclipse, code-snippets

How can I export my Eclipse Snippets so that I can re-use them on another machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Display the snippets view: Window -> Show View -> Other ... -> General -> Snippets

Right click in snippets view -> Customize ...

Select Snippet Category

Export

Comment: This only does one category? If you have multiple categories you have to do each one???

Answer (score 2):

If you add a new snippet a wizard opens. In that window you can export your snippets!

Comment: @Paul: Can you accept the answer with the grey hook please? But only if it the right one!

Comment: I added the answer, but voted the other answers up as they were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on exactly what you mean by snippets. For Java (and other languages) you can define custom templates, as well as the default ones created by Eclipse.

In Window... Preferences, filter for templates. In the dialog on the right-hand side are buttons for import and export. Select the templates you'd like to export, and click Export...

Save them to a file.

In the other workspace, go to the same location, but do an import, and select the file you created above. This will add the saved templates to the list.

Java also has Code Templates defined (i.e. pieces of code that get put in when you create a new method, class etc). The process is similar here for import/export.

Comment: very helpful, but it's specifically snippets I'm after - see my answer